# Was there an input device capable of entering all Algol 60 symbols with correct appearance?

Tags: history, keyboards, algol, character-sets

This question was inspired by [recent discussion](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/16051/why-do-keyboards-have-an-asterisk) on early keyboards and character sets, and mention in passing about how the [COBOL designers](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/15988/what-did-the-dod-think-fortran-lacked) were concerned about not using "non-existent" symbols.

Did any computer input device carry all characters required to write Algol 60 as it appeared in the reference language?

The complete set of Algol Basic Symbols (per the [Revised Report](http://www.softwarepreservation.org/projects/ALGOL/report/Algol60_report_CACM_1960_June.pdf) are these:

Letters: A-Z   a-z
Digits: 0-9
Arithmetic operators: +  −  ×  /  ÷  ↑
Relational operators: <  ≤  =  ≥  >  ≠
Logical operators: ≡  ⊃  ∨  ∧  ¬
Sequential operators: **goto**  **if**  **then**  **else**  **for**  **do**
Separators: ,  .  ₁₀  :  ;  :=  ␣  **step**  **until**  **while**  **comment**
Brackets: (  )  [  ]  ‘  ’  **begin**  **end**
Declarators: **own**  **Boolean**  **integer**  **real**  **array**  **switch**  **procedure**
Specificators: **string**  **label**  **value**
Boolean values: **true**  **false**

Due to limitations in the site markup language, the symbols that are written in boldface are to be understood as being underlined; the reference language uses underlining (as available on typewriters), though publications often use boldface, as I have done here.

Technically, each underlined word is to be considered as a single indivisible symbol which has no relationship to the individual letters of which it is composed.  The same consideration applies to the becomes-symbol := and the subscript-10 symbol ₁₀ (both of which are made up of two characters in this posting).

If I have counted correctly, there are 116 distinct symbols.

---

I should clarify what I mean by "Did any computer input device carry all characters?".

I do not require that for each basic symbol, that a single keystroke represent the symbol on input.  Pretty obviously, it's unlikely to be true in cases such as **begin**, which is more likely to require at least 7 keystrokes: underline-on, the letters b,e,g,i,n, and underline-off.  The operations of underline and overstrike can be used to build up a symbol from parts. Less-than-or-equal might, for example, be underlined-less-than.  Not-equals might be equals-backspace-slash.  The becomes-symbol can be keyed as plain old colon, equals.

HOWEVER, the printed/displayed symbol should be in some reasonable way look like the symbol in the reference language.  So, **begin** really has to be underlined and lowercase.  On the other hand, if there's an implementation that otherwise manages a high degree of fidelity to the Report except that it needs to use some stropping regime (like "begin" for **begin**), that would be interesting to see.

I'm not concerned for this question with the internal symbol encoding.  It's not relevant how many characters-worth of storage it takes to store **begin** in memory or on disc.  This is a question about source-language input.

Comment: Unicode has both ≔ (U+2254 COLON EQUALS) and ⏨ (U+23E8 DECIMAL EXPONENT SYMBOL).

Comment: Not really related to ALGOL, but at least the Sinclair ZX-80 BASIC family used individual character codes for all keywords at the UI level (not just the internal representation). For example to enter PRINT you had to type `P` at the beginning of a statement line and the interpreter inputted and displayed the “character” `PRINT`. And that wasn’t a shortcut but a single character, 0xF5. You couldn’t use P followed by R followed by... etc. even if you wanted to. Also, `>=` was one character code, distinct from the combination of `>` followed by `=`. And so on. So, such things have been done.

Comment: The KDF9 software (the PROMPT program development system, or Eldon2 multi-access system, which used PROMPT disc formats) encoded all Algol Basic Symbols as 8-bit values.  It was the job of the input device handlers to convert from device representation (and character code; cards, paper tape, and printers were all different) to Algol Basic Symbols. For online access, a PDP-8 handled the terminals, and assembled symbols from its input stream: so !BEGIN on an ASR 33 would end up as the single 8-bit symbol __begin__, before the Algol compiler even saw it.

Comment: Were the underlines a required part of the language, or were they only markup in the documents describing the language to indicate an indivisible token?

Comment: I don't recall any of the B5000 peripherals having anything approaching the full set, in fact I think they were an early user of digraphs. However I believe that they used a Friden as the controlling terminal (SPO), and there were a small number of cases where × (multiply) was required in a typed command or equivalent punched card.

Comment: Underlines (or equivalent) are syntactically required, as a consequence mainly of spaces having no significance. 'for j :=' is an assignment to a single identifier; '__for__ j :='  is the start of a for-loop statement.   Another way to look at this is that there are no reserved words; instead, user-invented identifiers and language keywords use different typefaces and can therefore be lexically distinguished.

Comment: 'Ignoring spaces' was popular at the time: both FORTRAN and Algol chose that. I would guess it follows from the fact that punch cards were sold pre-punched with 80 spaces :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Except for the full set of upper- and lowercase letters, there was. The Soviet character encoding standard [GOST 10859-64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GOST_10859) included all of the ALGOL-60 special characters, and there were [card punchers](https://www.computer-museum.ru/histussr/m20perif.htm) controlled by electric typewriters (Consul-260) with a standard-compliant character set.

[image: GOST 10859 keyboard]

Note the lack of distinct Latin letters graphically equivalent to Cyrillics, allowing to fit all special characters into a regular keyboard.

Given that the ALGOL-60 Revised Report says, with regard to letters (2.1),

> This alphabet may arbitrarily be restricted, or extended with any
> other distinctive character (i.e. character not coinciding with any
> digit, logical value or delimiter).

of interest is the fidelity of representation of non-alphanumeric characters, which is achieved 100%, and of the keywords, which can be achieved by underlining or double-striking.

Comment: By the way,  ⏨ was standard on some ASR 33 teletypes; the aforementioned KDF9, running the Eldon2 multiaccess system, used teletypes. Algol 60 representation was painful in some spots, but oddly not for  ⏨.

Comment: @another-dave Then it is surprising that ⏨ had not made its way into any character encoding in the U. S. and nobody had the thought to include it in Unicode. I'm glad that I petitioned the Unicode committee to encode ⏨ when there was still some space available in the U+23xx region.

Comment: The Algol user guide and terminal-system user manuals refer to the teletype as using 'ISO code'. There's no picture of a keyboard and nor are teletype character codes given (this latter would be only be of concern to the PDP-8 front end, which converted to/from internal system encoding).  I suppose by a process of elimination I might figure out what ⏨ replaced.

Comment: @another-dave Given the [options](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#Examples_and_other_notations), it could have been an ampersand, a backslash, or a single quote.

Comment: @another-dave A peculiarity of the font of that typewriter was that all confusables were graphically disambiguated. I don't remember exactly how it was with `0` vs `O` (a slash on 0, and/or a curl on O), but I do remember that to disambiguate `∨` and `V`, the letter was styled as V̪. I have not seen that trick anywhere else.

Comment: The charset was basically ASCII-63, since the teletypes had `←`and `↑`. But they also had accent-grave (*aka* close-single-quote) at shift-P, which looks ASCII-65-ish, in place of `@`.  The remaining characters not mentioned in the system user's manual are `?`, `#` and backslash.  I find giving up `?` implausible.  So that leaves `#` and backslash.

Comment: Not having ? is not that implausible. Note that there is no ? on the GOST keyboard.

Comment: Maybe you're right. The Eldon2 terminal system used very terse prompts:  TYPE IDENT (ttys were slow, front-end memory was small).  They could have been even more terse with a question mark: IDENT?

Comment: @LeoB. Are you really the reason that we have ⏨ in Unicode? That's awesome.

Comment: @texdr.aft Yes, I am. I got annoyed that my BESM-6 emulator could not output all characters properly; and being able to attend a Unicode technical committee meeting in person helped. Actually, there was another annoyance: Unicode did not have less/greater than with slanted equal ⩽⩾ at first, only ≤≥,  but they were added quickly enough without my intervention.

Answer (score 3):

For clarity, I decided to move the KDF9 part of my question to an answer, since that is what it really is... I have no intention of accepting my own answer.

---

My submission for "most nearly fulfilling the requirements" was [Algol 60 on the English Electric KDF9](http://bitsavers.org/pdf/englishElectric/kdf9/KDF_9_Algol_Programming.pdf) using paper tape prepared on a Friden Flexowriter.  The Flexowriter had two cases of letters, and could do underlining.

So: letters, digits, underlined words: no problem. For the rest of the symbols, all were available *except* the following:

Logical-operators: ≡  ⊃  ∨  ∧  ¬  replaced by **eqv** **imp** **or** **and** **not**

String quotes: ‘  ’  replaced by **[** **]**  (underlined brackets)

Space indicator in strings: ␣ replaced by *

These symbols were produced by underlining:  ≤  ≥

and this by overstrike: ≠

So, out of 116 symbols to be represented, 8 could not be presented as they appear in the Report.  I award the KDF9-and-Flex combination a score of 108/116.

Is this the closest any implementation can come to absolute fidelity?

(Note, things got very sad if you subsequently wanted to print out your program on a lineprinter rather than punching tape for Flexowriter interpretation).

Comment: I wonder if the ICL Algol compiler was derived from the English Electric one.since ICL took over the EE computer section.  It didn't have overstrikes: It use # for  ≠, % for spaces and alphabetic equivalents for ≤ ≥.  http://www.chilton-computing.org.uk/acl/literature/manuals/icl1906a/p013.htm#mc3p3

Comment: No, they're unrelated. (KDF9 had two independent compilers - Whetstone Algol, Kidsgrove Algol; ICT/ICL had several, though maybe there was a common core. I have used #XALM [I think] on a 1903).  The Chilton guys might have written their own compilers anyway.