# Why ASCII paper tape has lower bit punched from the narrow side?

Tags: history, punched-cards, ascii, character-sets

ASCII was presented on paper tape where the lower 5 bits cross sprocket holes as following

[image]

While FIELDATA chose the other way

[image]

I found placing the higher, **flag** bits at the narrow side appealing, since you have 5 consecutive bits on one side for 26 characters. but why the contrary way was chosen?

[image]

REF: [Character Codes](http://www.quadibloc.com/crypto/mi060103.htm)

LINK: [I don't see why punched card is any better than fanfold tape, but I digress.](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/19595/17812)

Comment: I don't know the answer, but note that paper tape did not begin with 8-channel tape. I'd therefore suggest looking at earlier standards, say for 5-channel tape, to see if this usage could be derived by 'extension'.

Comment: @another-dave Well, 5-bit baudot-murry tape is frequency optimized, thus in a rather ravelled order. It won't become a meaningful reference.

Comment: I'd guess that it was mostly arbitrary along the lines of big endian and little endian or driving on the right or the left.  This was a day when no one considered industry wide standards.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to read it as octal, having the low order 3 bits grouped together is handy.  Many of the early ASCII tables showed the codes in octal.  HEX makes more sense once your computers begin to work on 8 bit bytes,  but earlier computers had units like 36 bit words that were divisible by 3, and this led people to use octal for a few years.

Punched cards are easier to edit.  If you ever had a program on paper tape that was missing a single comma,  you'll know what I mean.

Comment: Wow, I didn't take octal numbers into account.

Comment: As for tapes, I'm talking about using every fold of tape like a card. Plz see the link.

Comment: I worked on non-byte orientated paper tape or card using systems for several years before meeting a byte oriented machine.  I learned octal before hex and, at one time, I could read paper tape (but more slowly than punched cards).

Comment: I also leanred octal before hex.